# Need a service to monitor network traffic for every processes

Tags: software-recommendation, network-monitoring

Is there a tool as service which can monitor network traffic for every processes. So that I can use command-line to analyze the usage?

Comment: @Wiking `nethogs` can be used as command-line tool. But I need a tool also as service which means it can record the usage in background and let me query the usage using command-line.

Comment: @Wiking I don't care where to save output. Both are OK. And YES I need to run the service at system start so that I can analyze the network traffic since system boot.

Comment: @Bob Sorry, I don't understand what you mean... So you are "Wiking" and delete your answer and account. But why? Could you explain more clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments you need no logs saved on drive and wish to run the network monitor as system service enabled at system start. Let's do it.

Install `nethogs` utility:

```
sudo apt install nethogs
```

Create bash script inside your home directory (your can replace it with other directory) assuming your username is `bob`:

```
touch /home/bob/nethogs.sh
```

Make the created script executable:

```
chmod +x /home/bob/nethogs.sh
```

Open script in text editor and copy and paste its code:

```
#!/bin/bash
pipe=/tmp/nethogs_pipe

trap "rm -f $pipe" EXIT

if [[ ! -p $pipe ]]; then
    mkfifo $pipe
fi
exec 3<>$pipe
nethogs -t -a >&3 2>&1

exit 0
```

Save changes and close text editor. Next create another script to read named pipe created by `nethogs.sh` script:

```
touch /home/bob/netmon.sh
```

Make the script executable:

```
chmod +x /home/bob/netmon.sh
```

Copy and paste to `netmon.sh` the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

pipe="/tmp/nethogs_pipe"

while true
do
    if read line; then
        echo $line
    fi
done <"$pipe"

exit 0
```

At next step we have to convert the `nethogs.sh` bash script to system service. Create/open the file in editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/nethogs.service
```

and copy/paste the code (replace `bob` in `ExecStart` with your username):

```
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/bob/nethogs.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Save changes and close the file. Make the created service enabled at system start:

```
sudo systemctl enable nethogs.service
```

Start the `nethogs` service:

```
sudo systemctl start nethogs.service
```

and check its status:

```
sudo systemctl status nethogs.service
```

Finally `cd` to your home directory where `netmon.sh` script resides and execute the script:

```
./netmon.sh
```

To quit monitoring press `CTRL+C`. That's all.

If you want to save monitoring data to drive, replace content of the `nethogs.sh` script with the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
log="/var/log/nethogs.log"
err="/var/log/nethog.err"
nethogs -t -a > $log 2> $err

exit 0
```

and restart service:

```
sudo systemctl restart nethogs.service
```

Live monitor through named pipe will be disabled and output of the script will be saved to `/var/log/nethogs.log` file - just open it with `less` or `tail`, for example:

```
tail -f /var/log/nethogs.log
```

All of errors will be saved to `/var/log/nethogs.log` file. The `/var/log/nethogs.log` will be cleaned up everytime computer rebooted/service restarted, to disable files cleanup  and to enable output appending replace content of the `nethogs.sh` script with another code:

```
#!/bin/bash
log="/var/log/nethogs.log"
err="/var/log/nethog.err"
nethogs -t -a >> $log 2>> $err

exit 0
```

**Remark.** In nethogs command options `-t` and `-a` inside scripts can be replaced according to your version installed. In Ubuntu 18.04 nethogs version option `-t` means `tracemode` and option `-a`is `listen all interfaces`.

Comment: What's the reason behind all those pipes and redirections?

Comment: And what happens when the pipe's buffer is full and no more writes can be made by nethogs?

Comment: I will test your answer tomorrow. And regardless of the result, your effort worth upvote. Don't know why downvote this without an explaination.

Comment: I have tested it and found some problems. First, I guess you are using Ubuntu 18.04 right? As `nethogs` in Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't have `-a` option. So I install it from source. Second, I think I should execute script `./netmon.sh` to monitor instead of `./nethogs.sh`. Guess it is a typo. Finally, it still cannot meet my requirements as the log is almost unreadable. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: I found I can remove `-t` option to make it readable. Great!